# rqt_plot did not work

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I was learning beginner level tutorial, 6. Understanding ROS Topics with ROS **kinetic** on **Ubuntu**,
no new window appeared after running

```
rosrun rqt_plot rqt_plot
```

and the error info is:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py:1015: UserWarning: Unable to find pixel distance along axis for interval padding of ticks; assuming no interval padding needed.
  warnings.warn("Unable to find pixel distance along axis "
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py:1025: UserWarning: Unable to find pixel distance along axis for interval padding of ticks; assuming no interval padding needed.
  warnings.warn("Unable to find pixel distance along axis "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_plot/data_plot/mat_data_plot.py", line 107, in resizeEvent
    self.figure.tight_layout()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1754, in tight_layout
    rect=rect)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py", line 349, in get_tight_layout_figure
    pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py", line 128, in auto_adjust_subplotpars
    fig.transFigure.inverted())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 1775, in inverted
    self._inverted = Affine2D(inv(mtx), shorthand_name=shorthand_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 526, in inv
    ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 90, in _raise_linalgerror_singular
    raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346880/rqt_plot-did-not-work/) by [sustech_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/52596/sustech_noob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2020-03-17

Post score: 3

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, I'm also a beginner and had the same problem.
The problem was that my matplotlib was outdated or not installed (not sure honestly)
following this: https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html was the solution. Hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [kekebn](https://answers.ros.org/users/52944/kekebn/) with karma: 31 on 2020-03-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [svdeepak99](https://answers.ros.org/users/50599/svdeepak99/) on 2020-04-10**:
Thank you so much for mentioning. That solved my issue finally.  .

**Comment by [isaacasimov](https://answers.ros.org/users/55880/isaacasimov/) on 2020-06-29**:
Worked for me too!

**Comment by [hassaanaero](https://answers.ros.org/users/64113/hassaanaero/) on 2021-01-04**:
im still facing the error  i actually executed the following command
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib

**Comment by [mdmedina](https://answers.ros.org/users/68123/mdmedina/) on 2021-01-17**:
Following the first few steps outlined in this question solved the problem for me: https://answers.ros.org/question/356959/matplotlib-for-ros/

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have solved like;

```
python -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

---

Originally posted by [girayuzun](https://answers.ros.org/users/24517/girayuzun/) with karma: 21 on 2021-01-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1